# Why my constructor keep referencing default constructer in c++?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm learning c++ (20). Please see my code:

MyClass.h

```cpp
class Spec
{
private:
    int number;

public:
    Spec() = delete;
    Spec(int);
};

class MyClass
{
private:
    int id;
    Spec spec;

public:
    MyClass() = delete;
    MyClass(int, Spec);
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

Spec::Spec(int number)
{
    this->number = number;
}

MyClass::MyClass(int id, Spec spec)
{
    this->id = id;
    this->spec = spec;
}
```

It returns when compiling:

```
/src/Hai.cpp: In constructor ‘MyClass::MyClass(int, Spec)’:
/src/Hai.cpp:8:35: error: use of deleted function ‘Spec::Spec()’
    8 | MyClass::MyClass(int id, Spec spec)
```

I'm not using any of default constructors, And I even deleted it to be sure. I'm not calling default constructor of these classes anywhere, and I don't want these classes to be default-constructed. Buy why the compiler still asking me there should be default constructor? Is there something to do with copy operation? Adding default constructor will be handle the error, but I just want to know why.

Comment: which include do you use ? Do you have a 'main' ?

Comment: Not sure why it is but it seems every beginner skips the section on *initialiser lists* when they are learning C++.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask]() where the first step is to "search and then research" and you'll find plenty of related SO posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`private: Spec spec;` and the fact that you don't have a member initializer list at the construcor of `MyClass` is causing the default constructor to run for `spec`.

Your code was initializing the members between `)` (end of parameters) and `{` (beginning of code) of the constructor and then assigning a new value in the constructor.

Use member initializers:

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass(int id, Spec spec)
: id{id}, spec{spec}                   //  <- member initializer list
{
}
```

```
id{id}
   ^ refers to the parameter id
^ refers to this->id
  ^  ^ uniform initialization curly braces
```

Comment: I thought there is no actual differences between using member initializer and doing it on my own.

Comment: @MyBug18 You thought wrong. The important part to understand is the difference between initialisation and assignment (what you call doing it on my own). If you don't use an initialiser list then every member of your class gets default initialised before your code executes.